# jS how to resize a text field? dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm wondering about how to resize a text feild automatically in crm 2011. Is it possible there?

For example, I've got a simple text field that has 3 lines by default.
And I'm looking for a method, which will resize a text field in order to show a data there without any scroll, if a wrote down 20 lines,.. whateever

Did anyone face that issue?

Comment: Are you looking to program a solution or intending to find an existing solution within the CRM product?

Comment: I think but I'm not sure it's coulbe solved by programming

Comment: Because if this is a programming question I would recommend moving it to Stack Overflow. As it stands, it is hard to tell.

Comment: I'm a bit confused a looked at a js solutions but It's another way, it's not a browser, but the js logic too